# Different layouts for cardViews in a RecycleView

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a RecycleView which contains fixed number of CardView (14 in my case) and some of these cards may be one of two types [layouts for cardView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OIZO.png). And.. my question is about how can I implement this in code?

I have class for a RecycleItem:

```
public class RecyclerItem {

private String title;
private String description;

public RecyclerItem(String _title, String _description, boolean _weekEnd) {
    this.title = _title;
    this.description = _description;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public void getWeekEnd(boolean _weekEnd){
    this.weekEnd = _weekEnd;
}

public boolean getWeekEnd(){
    return this.weekEnd;
}

}
```

and class for Adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<RecyclerItem> listItems;
private Context mContext;

public MyAdapter(List<RecyclerItem> listItems, Context mContext) {
    this.listItems = listItems;
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView title, description;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleOfTheCard);
        description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.descriptionOfTheCard);
    }
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position) {
    final RecyclerItem itemList = listItems.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(itemList.getTitle());
    holder.description.setText(itemList.getDescription());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listItems.size();
}

}
```

I just don't know how to change 'type' of c card while we filling the recycleView items list and how fill it correctly, so can you help me with that??

*And one another question. Do you know good literature about developing apps
for android?*

Comment: not understand your question because type not field in your pojo class.because every things written are correct.

Comment: implement getItemViewType in your adapter and inflate your views based on view type in OnCreateViewHolder @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return chatModelList.get(position).isMyMessage() ? ITEM_VIEW_OUTGOING : ITEM_VIEW_INCOMING;
    }